# What is the Chinese word for the technical term "slip factor" in fans?

Tags: vocabulary, technology

大家好！

I am communicating with a Chinese fan manufacturer and I want to ask them about the slip factor of their fans. By slip factor, I am referring to the ratio of the flow tangential velocity to the rotational speed of the fan blades. See this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_factor

I know it's a long shot that anyone here would know this - thank you in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slip factor = 滑移系数

[This paper](http://zzs.ujs.edu.cn/pgjx/EN/abstract/abstract1293.shtml#) provides both Chinese and English version of title and abstract:

Precision comparison on **slip factor** of centrifugal pumps = 离心泵**滑移系数**精度的比较

Comment: Yes, it is also called "滑动系数" or "滑率".

Comment: Thank you both so much! This is exactly what I needed.